# how do I compile different chapters with only a subset of the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I am using `\input{chapterXX}` to include different chapters in the main tex file, and use `\includeonly{chapterXX}` with several tex files, each time compiling only a single chapter, so I have multiple PDFs (one per chapter).

However, the tex files for the different chapters naturally include citation commands, and the citation commands are not ignored by the `\includeonly`. This means that when finally trying to print the bibliography for each chapter, the bibliography for the whole manuscript is printed. Is there a way to make the `\includeonly{}` command also include only citation commands from the specific chapter?

Comment: That is by design and the use-case for includeonly, to keep references and cites intact. How are you citing? This is an important fact, i think the modern biblatex can handle the situation.

Comment: Fairly straightforward with `biblatex` as @Johannes_B says. Or I think `chapterbib` or similar can handle this with `bibtex`.

Comment: Have a look for refsection in biblatex, I'm sure that I've answered a similar question on this site somewhere...

Comment: presumably you are using `\include{chapterXX}` not `\input{chapterXX}` since `includepnly` would have no effect otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, very straight forward using the modern package `biblatex` along with `biber`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\includeonly{\jobname-mary,\jobname-peter}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-peter.tex}
    \cite{ctan,companion}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-paul.tex}
    \cite{aristotle:physics,westfahl:space}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-mary.tex}
    \cite{herrmann,shore}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\include{\jobname-peter}
\include{\jobname-paul}
\include{\jobname-mary}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```